# How to get the differences between two - kind of - duplicated tables (sql)

Tags: sql, database, primary-key

***Prolog:***
I have two tables in two different databases, one is an updated version of the other. For example we could imagine that one year ago I duplicated table 1 in the new db (say, table 2), and from then I started working on table 2 never updating table 1.

I would like to compare the two tables, to get the differences that have grown in this period of time (the tables has preserved the structure, so that comparison has meaning)

My way of proceeding was to create a third table, in which I would like to copy both table 1 and table 2, and then count the number of repetitions of every entry.

In my opinion, this, added to a new attribute that specifies for every entry the table where he cames from would do the job.

***Problem:***
Copying the two tables into the third table I get the (obvious) error to have two duplicate key values in a unique or primary key costraint.

How could I bypass the error or how could do the same job better? Any idea is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want if A and B have the same structure, otherwise just select and rename the columns you want to confront....

```sql
SELECT 
   *
FROM   
   B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM A)
```

if NOT EXISTS doesn't work in your DBMS you could also use a left outer join comparing the rows columns values.

```
SELECT 
   A.* 
from
  A left outer join B
  on A.col = B.col and ....
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I solved creating a new primary key made of two attributes: the primary key of table 1 (or 2) + an attribute that I created from scratch that says from which table the entry is taken